# Explicitly disabling UIView animation in iOS4+

Tags: ios, animation, explicit

I have been reading that Apple recommends to use block-based animations instead of CATransaction

Before, I was using this code to disable animations:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions: YES];
// !!! resize
[CATransaction commit];
```

Is there a new recommended method to do this, or is this still okay?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
//animate here
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: The problem with using the `UIView` approach is that you cannot nest it like you can with `CATransaction` approach. So if you had a block of code that disabled animations and made a call to something else that disabled animations _inside_ that block the animations would be reenabled before the end of your block.

Comment: easy way to fix that is to check what the state was, using `areAnimationsEnabled` and then restore it to that after you're done

Comment: What can i do, if i need to disable animation for concrete view object? Not for all Views

Comment: @JoshuaWeinberg I am facing an issue when using this, could you please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806816/orientation-without-animation-giving-weird-result-when-uialertview-is-present

Answer (score 27):

For iOS 7 and above this can now be accomplished with:

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
    // Changes we don't want animated here
    view.alpha = 0.0;
}];
```

Comment: I still don't get the use-case for this. Why would I bother wrapping this in a block? Why not just say "view.alpha = 0.0;" and be done with it?

Comment: @GregMaletic Because sometimes the code being run is already part of an animation somewhere else in the call stack. This allows the update to not be animated.

Comment: Ah…so the idea is that this is wrapped by some other [UIView animate] call, and this is a little internal set-aside, so I can include things in that animate block that I don't want animated?

Comment: Correct. Sometimes you also get caught up in an animation by the system.

Comment: Yep, I just found this and used it for this exact use-case: Getting caught up in a system animation, or perhaps an animation somewhere in legacy code that I couldn't find!

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 3+**

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            // Update UI that you don't want to animate
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

For MonoTouch (C#) users, here is a helper class:

```
public class UIViewAnimations : IDisposable
{
    public UIViewAnimations(bool enabled)
    {
        _wasEnabled = UIView.AnimationsEnabled;
        UIView.AnimationsEnabled = enabled;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        UIView.AnimationsEnabled = _wasEnabled;
    }

    bool _wasEnabled;
}
```

Example:

```
using (new UIViewAnimations(false))
    imageView.Frame = GetImageFrame();
```

Comment: Glad someone else found it useful. In gist form: https://gist.github.com/jfoshee/5008117

Answer (score 2):

```
// Disable animations
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)

// ...
// VIEW CODE YOU DON'T WANT TO ANIMATE HERE
// ...

// Force view(s) to layout
yourView(s).layoutIfNeeded()

// Enable animations
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```