# How to set iOS navigationItem prompt without animation?

Tags: ios

When I set

```
self.navigationItem.prompt = @"";
```

in `viewDidLoad`, it animates the `navigationBar` taller. I want to show it taller, but without the animation. How can I lose the animation?

Comment: Try using one of the methods from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443742/explicitly-disabling-uiview-animation-in-ios4

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
self.navigationItem.prompt = @"";
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```